# PHP Nested Loop Issue: Incorrectly Updating dataStartRow Variable in a Multi-dimensional Array Iteration

Tags: php, foreach

I want to calculate where the datatartRow but im having problems when the $dataStartRow resets to 7 after one loop of $row_groups

Result:

```
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=7
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=7
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
==============================
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=9
==============================
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=10
team_id=21 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=10
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=11
team_id=21 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=11
team_id=21 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=11
team_id=21 / datastartRow=8 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=11
team_id=21 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=11
```

Expected:

```
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=7
team_id=208 / datastartRow=8 / lastRow=7
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
team_id=207 / dataStartRow=7 / lastRow=8
team_id=208 / dataStartRow=8 / lastRow=8
==============================
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
team_id=209 / dataStartRow=9 / lastRow=9
=============================
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=10
team_id=211 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=10
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=11
team_id=211 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=11
team_id=211 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=11
team_id=211 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=11
team_id=210 / dataStartRow=10 / lastRow=11
team_id=211 / dataStartRow=11 / lastRow=11
```

The dataStartRow=9 will reset to dataStartRow=7 after one loop in $row_groups which currently in Team Group 2 array. How can I retain the 9 as the next default start value and so on? Should retain the last value after each loop in $row_groups

```
$row_groups = array(
    0 => array(
        "Team Group 1" => array(
            0 => array(
                "team_id" => 207,
                "team_name" => "Child Team"
            ),
            1 => array(
                "team_id" => 208,
                "team_name" => "Child Team 2"
            )
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        "Team Group 2" => array(
            0 => array(
                "team_id" => 209,
                "team_name" => "Child Team 3"
            )
        )
            ),
    2 => array(
        "Team Group 3" => array(
            0 => array(
                "team_id" => 210,
                "team_name" => "Child Team 4"
            ),
            1 => array(
                "team_id" => 211    ,
                "team_name" => "Child Team 5"
            )
        )
    ),
);

$columns = array(
    0 => 620,
    1 => 621,
    2 => 622,
    3 => 623,
    4 => 624
);

$dataStartRow = 7;

foreach($row_groups as $team_group) {
    foreach($team_group as $group => $teams) {
        $lastRow = $dataStartRow;

            foreach ($columns as $index => $iRoleId) {
                foreach ($teams as $team) {

                        echo "<pre>".print_r("team_id=".$team['team_id']." / "."datatartRow=".$dataStartRow." / "."lastRow=".$lastRow,true);
                        $lastRow = ($dataStartRow > $lastRow) ? $dataStartRow : $lastRow;

                        $dataStartRow++;
                }   

                // Reset Start Row
                $dataStartRow = 7;

            }
        echo "<pre>".print_r("==============================",true);
        $dataStartRow = $lastRow+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMHO this _completely_ lacks any proper explanation, of what exactly you are trying to "calculate" here to begin with. _Explain_ the logic of how these values in your expected output are supposed to come about.

Comment: @CBroe it was clear to me and I managed to fix it. Basically the issue is that there is a variable that changes and it is saved into some other variable that changes as well. The solution is to store it into another variable as well that does not change. I did just that and the test passed.

Comment: My apologies. Im trying to calculate which <tr> should i add my value in my table and thats the dataStartRow=7. But im having problems on the second array “Team Group 2” which resets the start value to 7 again. Each team_id represents a row and $columns is the <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to store it in a variable in the outer loop without changing that variable:

```
foreach($row_groups as $team_group) {
    foreach($team_group as $group => $teams) {
        $default = $lastRow = $dataStartRow;

            foreach ($columns as $index => $iRoleId) {
                foreach ($teams as $team) {

                        echo "<pre>".print_r("team_id=".$team['team_id']." / "."datatartRow=".$dataStartRow." / "."lastRow=".$lastRow."\n",true);
                        $lastRow = ($dataStartRow > $lastRow) ? $dataStartRow : $lastRow;

                        $dataStartRow++;
                }   

                // Reset Start Row
                $dataStartRow = $default;

            }
        echo "<pre>".print_r("==============================\n",true);
        $dataStartRow = $lastRow+1;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
<pre>team_id=207 / datatartRow=7 / lastRow=7
<pre>team_id=208 / datatartRow=8 / lastRow=7
<pre>team_id=207 / datatartRow=7 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=208 / datatartRow=8 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=207 / datatartRow=7 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=208 / datatartRow=8 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=207 / datatartRow=7 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=208 / datatartRow=8 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=207 / datatartRow=7 / lastRow=8
<pre>team_id=208 / datatartRow=8 / lastRow=8
<pre>==============================
<pre>team_id=209 / datatartRow=9 / lastRow=9
<pre>team_id=209 / datatartRow=9 / lastRow=9
<pre>team_id=209 / datatartRow=9 / lastRow=9
<pre>team_id=209 / datatartRow=9 / lastRow=9
<pre>team_id=209 / datatartRow=9 / lastRow=9
<pre>==============================
<pre>team_id=210 / datatartRow=10 / lastRow=10
<pre>team_id=211 / datatartRow=11 / lastRow=10
<pre>team_id=210 / datatartRow=10 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=211 / datatartRow=11 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=210 / datatartRow=10 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=211 / datatartRow=11 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=210 / datatartRow=10 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=211 / datatartRow=11 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=210 / datatartRow=10 / lastRow=11
<pre>team_id=211 / datatartRow=11 / lastRow=11
<pre>==============================
```

Comment: I didn't thought of the $default = $lastRow = $dataStartRow;. I appreciate it!